# Why am I getting an "invalid aggregate" error when trying to initialize this record in VHDL?

Tags: initialization, vhdl, record

I want to initialize a record. I have looked online and following the style of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642757/1406888), but I am getting these errors:

From Aldec Linter:

> Compile Architecture "TB_ARCHITECTURE" of Entity "ten_gig_filter_tb"
>   Error: COMP96_0079: mgmt_regs_rx_TB.vhd : (97, 65): Invalid aggregate.
>   Error: COMP96_0077: mgmt_regs_rx_TB.vhd : (97, 65): Undefined type of expression. Expected type 'tAPB_IBUS_RECORD'.

From XVHDL Linter:

> type of aggregate cannot be determined without context; 0 visible types match here, 32 matches.

Here is my code:

```
-- APB BUS - CPU interface
type tAPB_IBUS_RECORD is record

    pclk        : std_logic;                --APB Clock, all transactions are synced to this clock
    presetn     : std_logic;                --APB active low reset.
    pprot       : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); --APB protection encoding.
    pselx       : std_logic;            --slave select pin, when asserted, will activate the slave
    penable     : std_logic;            -- Enable pin is asserted by the master after the first clock cycle and consecutively until the 
                                        -- the end of transcation indicated by pready = '1'
    pwrite      : std_logic;            -- APB Write/Read signal - '1' Write with pselx= '1', '0' - Read along with pselx = '1'
    pstrb       : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); -- Write strobe to enable sparse data transfer on the write bus, 0 - byte lane on pwdata(7-0)
    paddr       : std_logic_vector(19 downto 0); -- 20 bit address bus
    pwdata      : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- 32 bit data bus 
end record;

signal iAPB_BUS_IN         : tAPB_IBUS_RECORD := (
                             pclk => '0', presetn => '0', pprot => (others => '1'),
                             pselx => '1', pwrite => (others => '0'), penable => '1',
                             pstrb => (others => '1'), paddr => (others => '0'),
                             pwdata => (others => '0')
                           );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this bit is wrong:

```
pwrite => (others => '0'),
```

It should be

```
pwrite => '0',
```

because `pwrite` is of type `std_logic`.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5eay

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes. Thanks.